# Google maps show and hide markers using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-markers

How do I show and hide markers using JavaScript and google maps?

I would like to use checkboxes to show and hide markers, at the minute I have two markers and three checkboxes. one to show and hide all and the others to show and hide each marker. I am not sure how to connect them to checkboxes and show/hide them respectively.

Sample of a marker I am using:

```
 var Jorvik = createMarker({
       position: {lat: 53.95697, lng: -1.08100},
  map: map,
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'},
            "<h1>JORVIK Viking Centre</h1><p>This is the home marker.<br/>test</p>");
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/mike43237/pen/qmEVLE

Answer (score 1):

You Can use `setVisible(true/false)` method for markers
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEPB7/6/)

see the toggleGroup() function

Comment: Will my markers work the same way? They seem to be created differently.

Comment: Yes ! , push it onto an global array and loop through it and use setVisible(true/false) function for each marker and similarly for other individuals marker separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use marker.setVisible function and set true or false:

```
 $('#your_checkbox_id').change(function() {       
     Jorvik.setVisible($(this).is(":checked"));               
 });
```

Create google map:

```
iMap.initialize('map');
var Jorvik = iMap.markerCreate('title', 53.95697, -1.08100,true);
```

Custom class for google map (you can set your option) :

```
var iMap = {
marker: null,
initialize: function(mapElementId) {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        streetViewControl: this.streetViewControl,
        scrollwheel: this.scrollwheel,
        navigationControl: this.navigationControl,
        minZoom: this.minZoom,
        maxZoom: this.maxZoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.95697, -1.08100),
        mapTypeId: 'Styled',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['Styled', google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]
        }
    };            
    var styelMap = [
        {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#ffffff' },
                { saturation: -100 },
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }, {
            featureType: 'landscape',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#ffffff' },
                { saturation: -100 },
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }, {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#ffffff' },
                { saturation: 0 },
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }, {
            featureType: 'administrative',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#ffffff' },
                { saturation: 0 },
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }
    ];

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElementId), mapOptions);
    this.map.mapTypes.set('Styled', new google.maps.StyledMapType(styelMap, { name: 'Compact map' }));       

},
markerCreate: function ( title, lat, lng ,draggable  ) {              
     this.marker=  new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            title: title,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: draggable

      });       
     google.maps.event.addListener(pin, "drag", function() {
        // $('#lat').html(pin.position.lat());
        // $('#lng').html(pin.position.lng());
     });

     return this.marker;


}
```

}

Comment: How do I get it visible when i click the checkbox again?

Comment: Oh ok, I've just been following the Google map documentation. Any suggestions on how to improve my code?

Comment: I'm getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined